# Unknown Error (code: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate)

Tags: wordpress, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I am running WordPress instance in Aws Lightsail. Once I started using CDN for my instance I am getting an Unknown error "code: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" when I am trying to connect tp Gsuite plugin. When I am trying to connect my CDN to my cache plugin, I am getting an error "Error: Error executing "ListDistributions" on "https://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/2018-11-05/distribution"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)". Could you please help me with the same.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here, are your domain pointing to the CDN or to the instance itself? Please note that if your domain is pointing to the CDN, you will need to configure the CDN to access the information using http (and not https) as you don't have a valid domain in pointing to the instance's IP.

Comment: Hi Jota, My domain is pointing towards the instance only. When I try to point my Domain to my CDN(http), I am getting an error 'DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN'.

Comment: So you obtain the "cURL error 60" error when enabling the CDN and connect it to the instance, right? In that case, how are you configuring the CDN to work with the instance? Are you using the IP address of the instance or your domain? In case you are using your domain (and you can access your site without problems using the browser), I suggest you contact the CDN's support team to know more about the error.

Answer (score 0):

/wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/functions.php

`add_filter('https_ssl_verify', '__return_false');`

Comment: Please stop posting the same answer multiple times

Comment: so sorry, I only want other people easy find way for fix. What I need to do now?